# Syntax error in "if" statement in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've got a syntax error with the following code.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set path=%1
set value=[%path:~-1%]
echo !value!
if !value!==[\] (
    echo success
)

if !value!==["] (
    echo success
)
```

with this it presents a syntax error:

```
%1="C:\batch\test"
```

while with this it works well:

```
%1=C:\batch\test
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` with the `^` character.

```
if !value!==[^"] (
    echo success
)
```

Otherwise batch thinks you're starting a string, which breaks the rest of your code.

(On an unrelated note, `path` already exists as a system variable; I'd recommend using a different variable for your code.)

Comment: Thanks Dark, it really helps me. I just forgot that " should start with ^. Plus, thanks for your attention about the variable path.